# Visual Studio Time saver options?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, customization

I was wondering how to customize my visual studio to code faster. I'm begginer, but saw few awesome things like autofilling for's or auto brackets when someone typed if/for/while etc. 
Ex. When I'll type for it will fill it similar to this :

```
for(int i = size_T ; i< lengh ; i++)
{

}
```

Comment: it is called code snippet, now you know the keyword to google it

Comment: Plugins like CodeMaid don't make it directly easier to code for, but provides niceties like Class Overviews or formatting comments.

Comment: I have this feature with visualassist although I rarely use it for for loops. If you are new I would not spend so much time with this. Its not like you will be writing a thousand lines of code a day (or even week) as a new programmer.

Comment: Thank you guys. I just spend 1h to search in yt "tips & tricks" etc.